# Assembly change return address

Tags: assembly, return

Is there a way that I can change a return address.

As I need to either return to where the program was when a interrupt occurred for one situation, but for another I need it to basically restart.

I am using a microcontroller program called sms32v50

Comment: You should specify which CPU architecture you're targeting.

Comment: If the code runs from Memory, YES.

Comment: It is running from memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the normal return path, just return (i.e. `ret`).

To restart, I would just jump to the initialization code via `jmp`. Note that you then have to deal with resetting the stack/heap at the location you are jumping to.

Comment: How would I go about resetting the stack?

Comment: Well, just set the stack pointer to the value it has when the "processor" boots. Generally, just reset everything to initial conditions, so it is safe to call your initialization routine again. The goal is to not carry over any baggage from the previous run.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know it's probably not the best methods but it gets the job done :)

Answer (score 0):

You could change the return address on the stack but that is just horrible!